# Canceling running job

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

Is there a way to cancel a job that is running?

The [answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56290735/how-to-cancel-running-schedule-job-in-iot-hub) implies that it is not possible. However if you create Azure IoT Central application, when you schedule a job, they give you the option to automatically cancel a running job when certain % of errors occur.

[image]

Is this something internal and not available to public, or are there some SDKs, REST calls or any other ways to achieve this in custom developed applications?

Comment: have a look at the REST APIs (version 1.2-preview) for Jobs in the IoT Central App: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/1.2-previewdataplane/jobs/stop Note, that the Api token from your IoT Central App can be used for Authorization header and your appId for appsubdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this something internal and not available to public, or are there some SDKs, REST calls or any other ways to achieve this in custom developed applications?

**Updated answer:**

As commented by [Roman Kiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8084828/roman-kiss), you can refer to [Jobs - Stop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/1.2-previewdataplane/jobs/stop)

**Note:**  The `API token` from your IoT Central App can be used for `Authorization header` and your `appId` for `appsubdomain`.

---

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/jobs/cancel-scheduled-job), you can cancel **scheduled** job via REST API but as of now no way to cancel **running** job.

```
POST https://fully-qualified-iothubname.azure-devices.net/jobs/v2/{id}/cancel?api-version=2020-05-31-preview
```

You can refer to [job_client.ts](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/9f4a50203f191e184764601e8f7dacfbd4580b30/service/src/job_client.ts), [job_client_requirements.md](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/9f4a50203f191e184764601e8f7dacfbd4580b30/service/devdoc/job_client_requirements.md#canceljobjobid-done) and [Cancel Jobs in running status](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/issues/464)